# Control Left doesn't move the cursor to the previous word

Tags: windows-8, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-vista, autohotkey

In no program that is capable of editing text (such as notepad, Notepad++, or Chrome) on either my Windows Vista or Windows 8 laptops does <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT</kbd> move the cursor to the previous word.

**Prior Troubleshooting Steps (other than researching):**

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT</kbd> moves the cursor to the next word.
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT</kbd> highlights the previous word.
3. I put the following line in AutoHotKey (and saved/reloaded the script) and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT</kbd> then moves the cursor to the next word (as it should):

   ^Left:: Send ^{Right}
4. As step 3 above, but the following line did nothing when I used <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT</kbd>.

   !Left:: Send ^{Left}

I'm at a loss. I run Avast Antivirus, Spybot, and ZoneAlarm Firewall on strict settings and scans aren't turning up anything. Rebooting in safe mode has no effect either.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running any other AutoHotkey scripts on these computers that have Ctrl or Left Arrow set as hotkeys?

If so and you are not using #IfWinActive or ~ then it's possible you are blocking yourself by having those keys Hooked.

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols

You can also try various methods of Sending those keys, SendRaw, SendInput, SendEvent etc... More details here:

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm

To verify that the keys are being read by your script...

Run a script with:

```
#InstallKeybdHook
~LCtrl & Left::
Send {RCtrl Down}{Left Down}{RCtrl Up}{Left Up}
```

Double Left Click AutoHotkey Script Tray Icon->Select View->Key history

Press Ctrl + Left and verify that your keys are being read.

If all the above has be tried, it is possible that some software on your system has Hooked your Keys and you will have to figure out what you installed recently and remove that program. Good luck.